# Userform Listbox Items as string, where each item refers to a column range on active worksheet

Tags: excel, range, listboxitem

**Background:** I have an excel file with columns from `A:AN`. The sheet is used to track the status of multiple parts. 1 row per part and each column refers to a different element of the part that is being tracked. (supplier, weight etc.)

Within the sheet I have a macro to generate a report, it selects a predefined range of columns, copies them into a new workbook and gives it a timestamp plus a little formatting to make it into the report format I wanted. This works a charm, no problems.

**My problem is** that now I want the user to be able to select the columns they want to be included in the report. I have created a user form with two list boxes. ListBox1 has the title of each column and I have set up the control buttons to allow single or multiple item selection and move them to ListBox2. I would like it so that when a command button is clicked each item shown in ListBox2 would represent a column and they would all be combined into a range that can then be used for my original code to create the report.

I have drawn a complete blank on this one. Everything is working up to the point of actually using the items in ListBox2 in a useful way to generate a range that can be used in my code later down the line. Any ideas on how I should proceed? Any help would be much appreciated.

What I have tried so far is:
1) add ItemData that refers to a range below each of my AddItem commands - This resulted in a compile error [Compile Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IxERJ.jpg)

2) declare each of the column titles as a range and I tried to add the range as an AddItem into the list box but I got a run-time error. [Run-Time Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WnpJr.jpg)

As i said, the code for the rest of the user form is doing what I wanted but I just dont know how to overcome or set out this next step. I have included all the code I have so far for your reference. Is there an easier way to do it other than list boxes?

```
Private Sub cmdMoveAllLeft_Click()
'Variable Declaration
Dim iCnt As Integer
'Move Items from ListBox1 to ListBox2
For iCnt = 0 To Me.ListBox2.ListCount - 1
Me.ListBox1.AddItem Me.ListBox2.List(iCnt)
'Me.ListBox1.ItemData(.NewIndex) = Me.ListBox2.ItemData(iCnt)
Next iCnt
'Clear ListBox1 After moving Items from ListBox1 to ListBox2
Me.ListBox2.Clear

End Sub

Private Sub cmdMoveAllRight_Click()
'Variable Declaration
Dim iCnt As Integer
'Move Items from ListBox1 to ListBox2
For iCnt = 0 To Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1
Me.ListBox2.AddItem Me.ListBox1.List(iCnt)
'Me.ListBox2.ItemData(.NewIndex) = Me.ListBox1.ItemData(iCnt)
Next iCnt
'Clear ListBox1 After moving Items from ListBox1 to ListBox2
Me.ListBox1.Clear
End Sub

Private Sub cmdMoveSelLeft_Click()
'Variable Declaration
Dim iCnt As Integer
'Move Selected Items from Listbox1 to Listbox2
For iCnt = 0 To Me.ListBox2.ListCount - 1
If Me.ListBox2.Selected(iCnt) = True Then
Me.ListBox1.AddItem Me.ListBox2.List(iCnt)
'Me.ListBox1.ItemData(.NewIndex) = Me.ListBox2.ItemData(iCnt)
End If
Next
For iCnt = Me.ListBox2.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
If Me.ListBox2.Selected(iCnt) = True Then
Me.ListBox2.RemoveItem iCnt
End If
Next

End Sub

Private Sub cmdMoveSelRight_Click()
'Variable Declaration
Dim iCnt As Integer
'Move Selected Items from Listbox1 to Listbox2
For iCnt = 0 To Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1
If Me.ListBox1.Selected(iCnt) = True Then
Me.ListBox2.AddItem Me.ListBox1.List(iCnt)
'Me.ListBox2.ItemData(.NewIndex) = Me.ListBox1.ItemData(iCnt)
End If
Next
For iCnt = Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
If Me.ListBox1.Selected(iCnt) = True Then
Me.ListBox1.RemoveItem iCnt
End If
Next

End Sub


Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Call ListboxArray
Call GenerateReport

End Sub
Private Sub ListboxArray()

  Dim vArray() As String
  Dim LB2Array() As Variant
  Dim i As Long

  LB2Array = SelectColumns.ListBox2.List 'creates a 2-dimensional variant array from list contents
  ReDim vArray(UBound(LB2Array, 1))
  For i = 0 To UBound(LB2Array, 1)
   vArray(i) = LB2Array(i, 0)
  Next
   MsgBox "Your listbox contains: " & vbCrLf & Join(vArray, vbCrLf)
 End Sub
Private Sub GenerateReport()

    'Unlock Sheet
    On Error Resume Next
            ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="LBFD16"
    Range(output of list box 2).Select '(Unsure of how to make the items from ListBox2 into the required range)
    Selection.Copy
    Workbooks.Add
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    'Format sheet
    Range("A1:J1").Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    Selection.Merge
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "**THIS DATA IS AN EXTRACT FROM THE LIVE TRACKING DOCUMENT FOR THIS VEHICLE PROGRAM - FOR LATEST STATUS PLEASE CONSULT THE LIVE PACKAGE TRACKER**"
    Range("A1:J1").Select
    Selection.Font.Bold = True
    Selection.Font.Italic = True
    With Selection.Font
        .Color = -16776961
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With

    Range("E2:G2").Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .WrapText = True
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    Selection.Merge
    Range("E2:G2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "THIS DATA WAS EXTRACTED ON -"
    Range("H2").Select
    Application.ActiveCell.Value = Now()
    Range("H2").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "[$-409]d/m/yy h.mm AM/PM;@"
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .WrapText = True
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .WrapText = True
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    Range("H2").Activate
    Selection.ColumnWidth = 16
    Range("E2:G2").Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .WrapText = True
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = True
    End With

    'Save Report
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=vbNullString, FileFilter:="Excel File (*.xlsx),*.xlsx"), _
        FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False

    'Switch back to original tracker
    Windows("LB636 ELECTRICAL PACKAGE TRACKER.xlsm").Activate

    'Lock sheet
    On Error Resume Next
            ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=False, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True, AllowFiltering:=True, AllowInsertingHyperlinks:=True, Password:="LBFD16"
End Sub
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

'Dim Initial_Check_Complete As Range
'Set Initial_Check_Complete = ActiveSheet.Range("A:A")

    With ListBox1
                .AddItem "Initial_Check_Complete"
                    '.ItemData(.NewIndex) = ActiveSheet.Range("A:A")
                .AddItem "Part Description (English)"
                    '.ItemData(.NewIndex) = ActiveSheet.Range("C:C")
                .AddItem "Apperance"
                    '.ItemData(.NewIndex) = ActiveSheet.Range("D:D")
                .AddItem "Part Description (German)"
                    '.ItemData(.NewIndex) = ActiveSheet.Range("E:E")
                         'more items continue 

End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Some images might help us a lot. If you have an error, show us your code - and tell us where the error is

Comment: Hi CallumDA, sorry I didn't post any images or code because I don't even know how to approach the problem and don't have much to show. I though about setting the listbox items as an array but then didn't know how to link this to a range for each item. I also set about declaring a range for each column heading and adding it as ItemData below each addItem command but this did not work either. When I am back at my desk tomorrow I will share the code I have so far. But if you had an idea about how I could set this out correctly it would be great!